# How can I create a dictionary in python that has random letters as keys with no duplicates?

Tags: python, dictionary, random, key

This is my code:

I create some random letters and I store them in variables, then I use this variables as keys in the dictionary. The problem is that the keys are duplicates because of the random letters. How can I fix that?

```
a = random.choice(string.ascii_letters).lower()
b = random.choice(string.ascii_letters).lower()
            .
            .
            .
z = random.choice(string.ascii_letters).lower()

alphabet = 
{'a':a,'b':b,'c':c,'d':d,'e':e,'f':f,'g':g,'h':h,
'i':i,'j':j,'k':k,'l':l,'m':m,'n':n,
'o':o,'p':p,'q':q,'r':r,'s':s,'t':t,
'u':u,'v':v,'w':w,'x':x,'y':y,'z':z}
```

Comment: Just a quick note on terminology. You aren't storing those random letters as _keys_ you're storing them as _values_. In `{'a': 'xyz', 'b': 'uvw'}`, `'a'` is a key and `'xyz'` is the value associated with that key.

Comment: BTW, it's rarely a good idea to create a whole bunch of separate but related named variables like your `a` to `z`. When you find yourself tempted to do that, see if you can put them into a collection (like a list or dict) instead.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't use separate `choice()` calls. Use [`random.sample()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.sample), picking from [`string.ascii_lowercase`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#string.ascii_lowercase) rather than lowercasing:

```
# pick 10 random keys, all unique
keys = random.sample(string.ascii_lowercase, 10)
```

If all you are doing is shuffling *all 26 letters*, then use `random.shuffle()`:

```
# list of 26 letters in random order
random_letters = list(string.ascii_lowercase)
random.shuffle(random_letters)
# map the alphabet to the random letters
alphabet = dict(zip(string.ascii_lowercase, random_letters))
```